# Cannot connect to Local Cosmos DB NoSql using Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-data-studio

I can connect to my local Azure Cosmos DB Emulator using default Browser data explorer or VS code Azure Databases extension.  "Azure Data Studio" with following connection Settings:
Connection type:  Cosmos DB No Sql
Connection String: AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=.......

Although not selected "Mongo account" getting following error and unable to connect.
Failed to parse the connection string. Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"

Thanks.

Exhausted google search, not found any solution. Most examples are for CosmosDB for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is only supported in Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API. It is not supported in No SQL API.
you can only connect to Mongo API through Azure Data Studio by installing the Mongo DB extension as explained here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb?view=sql-server-ver16.
Please log your feedback at https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/?q=cosmos+db.